# Proving an expression is not a perfect square

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

Let a, b and c be 3 odd, distinct prime numbers. I have to prove that the product $abc\frac{a+b}2\frac{a+c}2\frac{b+c}2$ cannot be a perfect square.

Since a, b and c are prime, we have that $\frac{a+b}2\frac{a+c}2\frac{b+c}2=k^2abc$, with $k$ natural for the product to be a perfect square. I tried applying AM-GM on $\frac{a+b}2\frac{a+c}2\frac{b+c}2$ and $abc$ but it didn't get me anywhere.

I'm pretty sure this is supposed to be solved with pretty basic theory, but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hint: $a$ divides this product $\frac{a+b}{2}\frac{a+c}{2}\frac{b+c}{2}$ and so it divides at least one of the factors. Can $a$ divide either $\frac{a+b}{2}$ or $\frac{a+c}{2}$?

Comment: Well, if it divides the first term then $\frac{a+b}2=ka$, which means that $a+b=2ka$, and $b=(2k-1)a$, which can only be true for $k=1$, otherwise $b$ wouldn't be prime. Interesting, let me see how I can use this.

Comment: Yes, and then with $k=1$ we would have $b=a$, while the problem states that $a,b,c$ are *distinct* primes. Now, do consider the third possibility, which is that $a$ divides $\frac{b+c}{2}$...

Comment: I noticed that $k$ can't be 1, but I don't know how to proceed. If $a$ divides $\frac{b+c}2$, then it also divides $b+c$. Same thing can be said about $b$ and $a+c$, as well as $c$ and $a+b$. This means $a+c=kb$ etc., but I can't seem to be able to continue.

Comment: ... And, WLOG, presume $a$ is the biggest of the three prime numbers. How can it then divide $\frac{b+c}{2}$?

Comment: It obviously can't. I should've thought of that. Thanks for all the help! I'll accept your answer if you decide to write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $K=abc\frac{a+b}{2}\frac{a+c}{2}\frac{b+c}{2}$ is a perfect square, with $a, b, c$ - distinct odd primes.

Without loss of generality, let $a$ be the biggest of the three primes.

As $a$ divides $K$, and $K$ is a perfect square, then $a^2$ must also divide $K$, so $a$ must divide $bc\frac{a+b}{2}\frac{a+c}{2}\frac{b+c}{2}$. Being coprime to $b$ and $c$, we conclude that $a$ divides one of: $\frac{a+b}{2}$, $\frac{a+c}{2}$, $\frac{b+c}{2}$. However, this is impossible, as:

- $a$ cannot divide $\frac{a+b}{2}$ because otherwise $a$ would also divide $a+b$ and therefore $a$ would divide $b$.
- Similarly, $a$ cannot divide $\frac{a+c}{2}$.
- Finally $a$ cannot divide $\frac{b+c}{2}$ either, because it is too big. As we assumed $a$ to be the biggest, i.e. $a>b, a>c$, we also have $a>\frac{b+c}{2}$.